# How to replace a string in Readable typescript?

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3

I am getting a file from aws s3 this way:

```
const s3Response = this.client.send(
      new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
      })
    )    
const responseBody: Readable = s3Response.Body as Readable
```

I need to replace some string in the `responseBody` and send it back to s3. I am sending it back by parts so I need to send Buffer type to s3 API.

How to replace string in `Readable` without casting it to `string` and then cast it to `Readable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find an option without casting to string but did that not for chunks not whole object:

```
const s3Response = this.client.send(
      new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
      })
    )    
const responseBody: Readable = s3Response.Body as Readable
for await (const chunk of readableBody) {
    buffer.push(Buffer.from(chunk.toString().replace("oldString", "newString")))
}
return Buffer.concat(buffer)
```